# shiny module selectInput is not reactive

Tags: r, input, module, shiny

For some reason using a selectInput in a module is not reacting to changes of the input value. I added a minimum example to demonstrate my issue. If I write the same code without a module, i.e. pasting the ui and server code of the module to the main server and ui functions without the namespace function works. 
I don't really see the issue with my code.

```
require(shiny)

ui <- function(){
    dummyUI("test")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    callModule(dummy, "test")
}

dummyUI <- function(id) {
    ns <-NS(id)
    uiOutput(width = 6, ns("selectMaterial"))
}

dummy <- function(input, output, session) {
    # render UI for the filters
    output$selectMaterial <- renderUI({
        selectInput(
            inputId = "selectMaterial",
            label = "Choose Materials" ,
            choices = c("a","b"),
            multiple = TRUE)
    })

    observeEvent(input$selectMaterial ,{print("hi")})
}

shinyApp(ui(), server)
```

Comment: Use `fluidPage()` instead of `function()` to define your `ui`, and change the last line to `shinyApp(ui, server)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) (section "Using renderUI within modules
"), you need to use the namespace function in `renderUI`.

```
require(shiny)

ui <- function(){
  dummyUI("test")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(dummy, "test")
}

dummyUI <- function(id) {
  ns <-NS(id)
  uiOutput(width = 6, ns("selectMaterial"))
}

dummy <- function(input, output, session) {
  # render UI for the filters
  output$selectMaterial <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      inputId = session$ns("selectMaterial"),       ## <= namespace here
      label = "Choose Materials" ,
      choices = c("a","b"),
      multiple = TRUE)
  })

  observeEvent(input$selectMaterial ,{print("hi")})
}

shinyApp(ui(), server)
```